# WCF and JSON binding

Tags: json, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-rest

I am trying to create a wcf service that returns json. I have some problems with my config file and i also don't know how to test it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ContactLibraryJSON.ContactLibrary">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="JSONEndpointBehavior"
          contract="ContactLibraryJSON.IContactServiceJSON" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.31/ContactLibraryJSON" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JSONEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I still get

> "Cannot add the behavior extension webhttp to the service behavior
>   names `JSONEndpointBehavior` because the underlying behavior type does
>   not implement the `IServiceBehaviorInterface`"

Contact is defined like :

```
[DataContract(Name="Contact")]
public class Contact
{        
    [DataMember(Name="FirstName")]
    public string firstName=null;
    [DataMember(Name="LastName")]
    public string lastName=null;
    [DataMember(Name="Email")]
    public string email=null;
    [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
    public int age = 0;
    [DataMember(Name = "Street")]
    public string street=null;
    [DataMember(Name = "City")]
    public string city=null;
    [DataMember(Name = "Country")]
    public string country=null;
}
```

IContactService is defined like :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContactServiceJSON
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "")]
    Contact GetContact();        
}
```

The implementation of `GetContact`:

```
public Contact GetContact()
{
    return new Contact()
    {
        firstName = "primulNume",
        lastName = "alDoileaNume",
        age = 33,
        city = "Cluj",
        country = "Romania",
        email = "ceva@mail.com",
        street = "Bizusa 8"
    };
}
```

My service runs on another computer in my lan. Base address is like: http://192.168.1.xxx/ContactLibraryService. `ContactLibraryService` is hosted by IIS and is converted to an application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not good that you have Service Contract `IContact` and Data Contact `Contact`. Rename Service Contract like `IContactService`.

```
<services>
  <service name="ContactLibrary.ContactService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ContactLibrary.IContactService"  behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

During Debug time (it looks you have WCF library), service address will be http://localhost:8732/contact

Comment: 'JSONEndpointBehavior' should be not Service but Endpoint behavior

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the `<webHttp/>` to the list of *endpoint* behaviors. Also, the endpoint needs to use the `webHttpBinding`. And finally, to respond to `GET` HTTP requests, you need to use the `WebGet` attribute (instead of `WebInvoke(Method="GET")`.

```
  <system.serviceModel> 
    <services> 
      <service name="ContactLibrary.ContactLibrary"> 
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="JSONEndpointBehavior" 
                  contract="ContactLibrary.IContact"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
        <endpoint address="ws"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="" 
                  contract="ContactLibrary.IContact" /> 
        <host> 
          <baseAddresses> 
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/ContactLibrary" /> 
          </baseAddresses> 
        </host> 
      </service> 
    </services> 
    <behaviors> 
      <endpointBehaviors> 
        <behavior name="JSONEndpointBehavior"> 
          <webHttp/> 
        </behavior> 
      </endpointBehaviors> 
      <serviceBehaviors> 
        <behavior> 
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information,  
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment --> 
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> 
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes,  
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment  
          to avoid disclosing exception information --> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> 
        </behavior> 
      </serviceBehaviors> 
    </behaviors> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And the service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]  
public interface IContact  
{  
    [OperationContract]  
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "contact")]  
    Contact GetContact(int idContact);        
}
```

Comment: i will edit the service on monday because it's a work task. i will post again if i succeded or the new error i get.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed bindings here you have to add webHttpBinding and basichttpbing under the bindings tab in system.serviceModel tag.

```
    <services>
  <service name="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.IntranetService" behaviorConfiguration="IntranetService.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.IIntranet">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
  <service name="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.MobileServicesController" behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
    <endpoint address="RestService" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior" contract="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.IMobileServices" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
             sendTimeout="10:15:00"
             openTimeout="10:15:00"
             receiveTimeout="10:15:00"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807"
             maxBufferPoolSize="9223372036854775807"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="StreamedRequest" >
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
    </binding>
    <!-- For Cyber Source bindings-->
    <binding name="ITransactionProcessor" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <!--Cyber Source bindings ends here-->
</bindings>
```

Comment: please change parameters according to your requirements and remain as it is other tags which you already added.